# Is it possible to control the position of plots to be front/back when combined using Show?

Tags: plotting

I have two plots and would like to combine using `Show`, the problem is that `show` reads the option of the first input and apply to the rest with keeping them stacked on top of each other as ordered in the input. How can I control the location to be in front/back without changing the order input in Show?

Here is an example with two inputs to `Show` `plot` and `plan`

```
plot = Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1, 1.5}}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, FontSize -> 22] &) /@ {"x", "y"}, 
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> {150, 150}, ImagePadding -> 80];
plan = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{-5, -0.75}, {5, 0.75}]}, 
   ImagePadding -> 80];
```

combine them with `Show` gives

```
Show[plot, plan]
```

[image]

So, how can I send the red rectangle to the back without changing the order of the input because it will modify the desired output?

Comment: why can't you change the order?  If you do not want the first graphics options to be used for all others, you can always provide options in `Show` itself, and that will override the first graphics options. This way you do not have to worry about the order.

Comment: I think changing the order and using the options of `plot` in `Show` (i.e., `Show[plan, plot, Options[plot]]` ) is the most straightforward way.

Comment: @kglr, That is exactly what I am looking for, thanks. May you please post as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Nasser, from my experience, when combining many figures imposing the options in Show does not give the desired results sometimes where some tiny anomalous showup.

Comment: `imposing the options in Show does not give the desired results sometimes` but isn't  using `Options[plot]` solution by kglr basically does this but in a more economical way? it says to `Show` to use the `plot` graphics options regardless of where that graphics is located in the order given.  And that is what I meant when I said this can be done by giving the desired options in `Show` itself.

Comment: @Nasser, you are right, but at least I don't face that problem now, and as I said it appears with some structures. The most elegant way might be using `Prolog` as suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short way to do it is to use the `Prolog` optino to create the red rectangle, but you will need some opacity to see the grid, if you use one.  (My grid is a default for `Plot`.)

```
Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue,
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1, 1.5}},
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16},
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 22], Style["y", 22]},
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> {150, 150}, ImagePadding -> 80,
  Prolog -> {Red, Opacity[.6], Rectangle[{-5, -0.75}, {5, 0.75}]}]
```

[image]

A second way is change the order of the input, but also move the `Plot` options to the `Show`, like this

```
plot = Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
plan = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{-5, -0.75}, {5, 0.75}]}, 
   ImagePadding -> 80];

Show[{plan, plot}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1, 1.5}}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16},
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 22], Style["y", 22]},
 ImageSize -> Automatic -> {150, 150}, ImagePadding -> 80]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can change the order and use the options for `plot` in `Show`. That is, use

```
 Show[plan, plot, Options[plot]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually a `Prolog` statement should be sufficient to put graphics before the plot so that these appear in the background.

```
Plot[
 Sin[2 x],
 {x, -5, 5},
 PlotStyle -> Blue,
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1, 1.5}}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 16},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, (* don't have Matex *)
 ImageSize -> Automatic -> {150, 150},
 ImagePadding -> 80,
 Prolog -> {Red, Rectangle[{-5, -0.75}, {5, 0.75}], ImagePadding -> 80}
 ]
```

and the `ImagePadding` on the last line is not doing much inside the `Graphics` so you can remove it.

[image]